# Mongodb delete object from nested arry using $pull not working using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
   [
    {
      "reports": [
    {
      "imageid": 1888,
      "name": "hello"
    },{
      "imageid": 2344,
      "name": "hello"
    }
      ],
      "report_name": "a"
    },{
    "reports": [
    {
      "imageid": 1888,
      "name": "hello"
    },{
      "imageid": 2344,
      "name": "hello"
    }
      ],
      "report_name": "b"
    }
   ]
```

Here is my mongodb structure. I wants to delete object from reports array where imageid is 1888. Just example in first reports there are 2 objects after delete imageid 1888 there will be onnly one reports (2344 imageid object only).

```
db.reports.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { reports: { imageid: 1888 } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

This code i am trying in mongodb shell and it is working fine.
But below code is using python-pymongo. That piece of code is not working.

```
mycol.update(
        {}, 
        { "$pull": { "reports": {"imageid": imageid} } },
        {"multi":"true"}
       )
```

Here is the errors i am getting while making the query from python using pymongo

```
  File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhubfractal_rb/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/fractal/consumerhubfractal_rb/report/views.py", line 45, in report
    {"multi":"true"}
  File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhubfractal_rb/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2535, in update
    collation=collation)
  File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhubfractal_rb/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 732, in _update
    common.validate_boolean("upsert", upsert)
  File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhubfractal_rb/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 132, in validate_boolean
    raise TypeError("%s must be True or False" % (option,))
TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

I tried adding upsert=True but still got another error.

Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
mycol.update( { }, { "$pull": { "reports": {"imageid": int(imageid)} } }, multi=True )
```